# Simple RDD write to DynamoDB in Spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

Just got stuck on trying to import a basic RDD dataset to DynamoDB. This is the code:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf

var rdd = sc.parallelize(Array(("", Map("col1" -> Map("s" -> "abc"), "col2" -> Map("n" -> "123")))))

var jobConf = new JobConf(sc.hadoopConfiguration)
jobConf.set("dynamodb.output.tableName", "table_x")
jobConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat")

rdd.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf)
```

And this is the error I get:

```
16/02/28 15:40:38 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 7.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 18, ip-172-31-9-224.eu-west-1.compute.internal): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DefaultDynamoDBRecordWriter.convertValueToDynamoDBItem(DefaultDynamoDBRecordWriter.java:10)
at org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.AbstractDynamoDBRecordWriter.write(AbstractDynamoDBRecordWriter.java:90)
at org.apache.spark.SparkHadoopWriter.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:96)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1199)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1197)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1250)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1205)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1$$anonfun$13.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1185)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to convert your objects to Text objects.

I suggest you have a look here:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/using-spark-sql-for-etl/