# Spark 2.2.0 - How to write/read DataFrame to DynamoDB

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr

I want my Spark application to read a table from DynamoDB, do stuff, then write the result in DynamoDB.

## Read the table into a DataFrame

Right now, I can read the table from DynamoDB into Spark as a `hadoopRDD` and convert it to a DataFrame. However, I had to use a regular expression to extract the value from `AttributeValue`. Is there a better/more elegant way? Couldn't find anything in the AWS API.

```
package main.scala.util

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import scala.util.matching.Regex
import java.util.HashMap

import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.model.AttributeValue
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable
/* Importing DynamoDBInputFormat and DynamoDBOutputFormat */
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable

object Tester {

  // {S: 298905396168806365,} 
  def extractValue : (String => String) = (aws:String) => {
    val pat_value = "\\s(.*),".r

    val matcher = pat_value.findFirstMatchIn(aws)
                matcher match {
                case Some(number) => number.group(1).toString
                case None => ""
        }
  }


   def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    val sparkContext = spark.sparkContext

      import spark.implicits._

      // UDF to extract Value from AttributeValue 
      val col_extractValue = udf(extractValue)

  // Configure connection to DynamoDB
  var jobConf_add = new JobConf(sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
      jobConf_add.set("dynamodb.input.tableName", "MyTable")
      jobConf_add.set("dynamodb.output.tableName", "MyTable")
      jobConf_add.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat")
      jobConf_add.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat")


      // org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.DynamoDBItemWritable)]
      var hadooprdd_add = sparkContext.hadoopRDD(jobConf_add, classOf[DynamoDBInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[DynamoDBItemWritable])

      // Convert HadoopRDD to RDD
      val rdd_add: RDD[(String, String)] = hadooprdd_add.map {
      case (text, dbwritable) => (dbwritable.getItem().get("PIN").toString(), dbwritable.getItem().get("Address").toString())
      }

      // Convert RDD to DataFrame and extract Values from AttributeValue
      val df_add = rdd_add.toDF()
                  .withColumn("PIN", col_extractValue($"_1"))
                  .withColumn("Address", col_extractValue($"_2"))
                  .select("PIN","Address")
   }
}
```

## Write the DataFrame to DynamoDB

Many answers in stackoverflow and elsewhere only point to the [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/analyze-your-data-on-amazon-dynamodb-with-apache-spark/) and the [emr-dynamodb-hadoop github](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector). None of those resources actually demonstrate how to write to DynamoDB.

[I tried converting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43248940/how-to-convert-dataframe-in-spark-to-hadooprdd) my `DataFrame` to `RDD[Row]` unsuccessfully.

```
df_add.rdd.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf_add)
```

What are the steps to write this DataFrame to DynamoDB? (Bonus Points if you tell me how to control `overwrite` vs `putItem` ;)

Note: `df_add` has the same schema as `MyTable` in DynamoDB.

**EDIT**: I am following the recommendation from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733968/simple-rdd-write-to-dynamodb-in-spark) which points to this post on [Using Spark SQL for ETL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/using-spark-sql-for-etl/):

```
// Format table to DynamoDB format
  val output_rdd =  df_add.as[(String,String)].rdd.map(a => {
    var ddbMap = new HashMap[String, AttributeValue]()

    // Field PIN
    var PINValue = new AttributeValue() // New AttributeValue
    PINValue.setS(a._1)                 // Set value of Attribute as String. First element of tuple
    ddbMap.put("PIN", PINValue)         // Add to HashMap

    // Field Address
    var AddValue = new AttributeValue() // New AttributeValue
    AddValue.setS(a._2)                 // Set value of Attribute as String
    ddbMap.put("Address", AddValue)     // Add to HashMap

    var item = new DynamoDBItemWritable()
    item.setItem(ddbMap)

    (new Text(""), item)
  })             

  output_rdd.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf_add)
```

However, now I am getting `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text` despite following the documentation ... Do you have any suggestion ?

**EDIT 2**: Reading more carefully this post on [Using Spark SQL for ETL](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/using-spark-sql-for-etl/):

> After you have the DataFrame, perform a transformation to have an RDD that matches the types that the DynamoDB custom output format knows how to write.  The custom output format expects a tuple containing the Text and `DynamoDBItemWritable` types.

Taking this into account, the code below is exactly what theAWS blog post suggest, except I cast `output_df` as an rdd otherwise `saveAsHadoopDataset` doesn't work. And now, I am getting `Exception in thread "main" scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference: illegal cyclic reference involving object InterfaceAudience`. I am at the end of my rope!

```
      // Format table to DynamoDB format
  val output_df =  df_add.map(a => {
    var ddbMap = new HashMap[String, AttributeValue]()

    // Field PIN
    var PINValue = new AttributeValue() // New AttributeValue
    PINValue.setS(a.get(0).toString())                 // Set value of Attribute as String
    ddbMap.put("PIN", PINValue)         // Add to HashMap

    // Field Address
    var AddValue = new AttributeValue() // New AttributeValue
    AddValue.setS(a.get(1).toString())                 // Set value of Attribute as String
    ddbMap.put("Address", AddValue)     // Add to HashMap

    var item = new DynamoDBItemWritable()
    item.setItem(ddbMap)

    (new Text(""), item)
  })             

  output_df.rdd.saveAsHadoopDataset(jobConf_add)
```

Comment: I am having the similar scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$CyclicReference error, any help please?

Comment: I did not find a solution and used S3 instead.

Comment: this is lot easier way for reading from DynamoDB,  val simple2: RDD[(String)] = data.map { case (text, dbwritable) => (dbwritable.toString)} and then spark.read.json(simple2).registerTempTable("gooddata") and then spark.sql("select replace(replace(split(cast(address as string),',')[0],']',''),'[','') as housenumber from gooddata").show(false)

Comment: @Béatrice Moissinac do you have a soluton for it now ...please share github link if possible

Answer (score 7):

I was following that "Using Spark SQL for ETL" link, and found the same "illegal cyclic reference" exception.
The solution for that exception is quite simple (but it cost me 2 days to figure out) as below. The key point is to use map function on the RDD of the dataframe, not the dataframe itself.

```
val ddbConf = new JobConf(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
ddbConf.set("dynamodb.output.tableName", "<myTableName>")
ddbConf.set("dynamodb.throughput.write.percent", "1.5")
ddbConf.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat")
ddbConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat")


val df_ddb =  spark.read.option("header","true").parquet("<myInputFile>")
val schema_ddb = df_ddb.dtypes

var ddbInsertFormattedRDD = df_ddb.rdd.map(a => {
    val ddbMap = new HashMap[String, AttributeValue]()

    for (i <- 0 to schema_ddb.length - 1) {
        val value = a.get(i)
        if (value != null) {
            val att = new AttributeValue()
            att.setS(value.toString)
            ddbMap.put(schema_ddb(i)._1, att)
        }
    }

    val item = new DynamoDBItemWritable()
    item.setItem(ddbMap)

    (new Text(""), item)
}
)

ddbInsertFormattedRDD.saveAsHadoopDataset(ddbConf)
```

Comment: https://github.com/kali786516/Spark2StructuredStreaming/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataframe/part11/kinesis/consumer/KinesisSaveAsHadoopDataSet/TransactionConsumerDstreamToDynamoDBHadoopDataSet.scala , full example for any one

Answer (score 0):

I hope that I'm not too late for the party to save others time and effort. I've been struggling with this spark -> dynamodb stuff using the [emr-dynamodb-connector](https://github.com/awslabs/emr-dynamodb-connector) (mostly dependencies conflict issues like missing classes or methods) and it took me hours to find out that I need to include the `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb` package in my pom.xml because of the version constraints of other aws packages. AWS published a [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/EMR-Serverless-UserGuide/using-ddb-connector.html) about it but I find it quite superficial (step 3 is lacking some variable declarations and step 2 is not necessary in my case) and it does not show you how to choose the compatible version with Spark and Hadoop).

Answer (score -2):

This is somewhat simpler working example.

For Writing to DynamoDB from Kinesis Stream for Example using Hadoop RDD:-

https://github.com/kali786516/Spark2StructuredStreaming/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/dataframe/part11/kinesis/consumer/KinesisSaveAsHadoopDataSet/TransactionConsumerDstreamToDynamoDBHadoopDataSet.scala

For reading from DynamoDB using Hadoop RDD and using spark SQL without regex.

```
val ddbConf = new JobConf(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
    //ddbConf.set("dynamodb.output.tableName", "student")
    ddbConf.set("dynamodb.input.tableName", "student")
    ddbConf.set("dynamodb.throughput.write.percent", "1.5")
    ddbConf.set("dynamodb.endpoint", "dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com")
    ddbConf.set("dynamodb.regionid", "us-east-1")
    ddbConf.set("dynamodb.servicename", "dynamodb")
    ddbConf.set("dynamodb.throughput.read", "1")
    ddbConf.set("dynamodb.throughput.read.percent", "1")
    ddbConf.set("mapred.input.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.read.DynamoDBInputFormat")
    ddbConf.set("mapred.output.format.class", "org.apache.hadoop.dynamodb.write.DynamoDBOutputFormat")
    //ddbConf.set("dynamodb.awsAccessKeyId", credentials.getAWSAccessKeyId)
    //ddbConf.set("dynamodb.awsSecretAccessKey", credentials.getAWSSecretKey)


val data = spark.sparkContext.hadoopRDD(ddbConf, classOf[DynamoDBInputFormat], classOf[Text], classOf[DynamoDBItemWritable])

val simple2: RDD[(String)] = data.map { case (text, dbwritable) => (dbwritable.toString)}

spark.read.json(simple2).registerTempTable("gooddata")

spark.sql("select replace(replace(split(cast(address as string),',')[0],']',''),'[','') as housenumber from gooddata").show(false)
```

Comment: Your link is a 404